# Display list of all values of a custom field

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, advanced-custom-fields

How can I retrieve a list of all values of a specific custom field throughout all posts?

I have a custom field titled "issue_number" and each post is given a numerical value based on the issue to which it belongs. I am trying to display all values of this field to achieve something like this:

-Issue 1
-Issue 2
-Issue 3

Each time a unique value is given to "issue_number", that value will be added to the list.

Answer (score 1):

You're gonna have to make use of the [`$wpdb` class](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) to make a custom query, then use [`array_unique`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) to remove all duplicates. See the code below :

```
global $wpdb;
$issues = $wpdb->get_col( "
    SELECT pm.meta_value
    FROM {$wpdb->postmeta} pm
    WHERE pm.meta_key = 'issue_number'
" );
$issues = array_unique($issues);
```

That should do it !

Answer (score 0):

Referring to the Wordpress documentation it has the ability by default to fetch single or multiple entries of a custom field. Surely you just use this?

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/